# Ruby on Rails - How to use External Class in App Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently trying to teach myself Ruby on Rails. I set up a new app and got it up and running and then I created a new class - `Player` and saved it in the `app > models` directory (as from what I have read it is auto loaded from here):

**player.rb**

```
class Player
  @@players = {}
  def initialise(name, rating=50)
    @name = name
    @rating = rating
    @@players[name] = rating
  end

  def getName()
    return @name
  end
end
```

**index_controller_rb**

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
    def index
      player1 = Player.new("Martin", 90)
    end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Test</h1>


<%=  player1.getName() %>
```

The error I get is

`wrong number of arguments(2 for 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done this right and assumed things correctly.  The error tells you that you found the class, but the method you are trying to call does not support 2 arguments. The default `initialize` method accepts zero arguments, when when you send it two it explodes on you.

This is because you simply misspelled the `initialize` method name, so you didn't override it with the version that takes 2 arguments.

This:

```
def initialise(name, rating=50)
```

Should be:

```
def initialize(name, rating=50)
#           ^ a "z" here
```

Now when `Player.new("Martin", 90)` is called your version of `initialize(name, rating)` will be properly invoked.

---

Secondly, you seem to want to pass the player to your view.  To do this, the player needs to be an instance variable (start with an `@` sign).  Otherwise it's a local variable, and never leaves the scope of the `index` controller method.  Instance variables are passed along to your view.

Controller:

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @player1 = Player.new("Martin", 90)
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= @player1.getName %>
```

Comment: ah ******, thank you. I hate making questions for it to be such a trivial mistake. I get a different error now `undefined local variable or method `player1' for #<#<Class:0x3cdbfd8>:0x3cdfe48>` any idea what that's about to save my sanity?

Comment: make `player1` an instance variables by adding `@`, so `@player1 = Player.new("Martin", 90)` is what you want

Comment: You said he did the things right, he stored the external class in models. Is that the right place to store the class or lib/tasks is the right place?